# Style div to retrieve same dimensions as image inside

Tags: html, css, image

I need to position a div (or button) in such a way that it has the same dimensions as the image it contains.

At the same time the image and div (`.zoom`) may not exceed the dimensions of the parent div(s).

The `aqua` div for the horizontal image is larger than the image itself.

I've tried around quite a bit, but I'm not able to get it working for the vertical as well as horizontal image.

If I get the box for the horizontal image right, the vertical image overflows to the bottom.

For context: I have no control over the image itself (might come in all aspect ratios and sizes) and the most outside div (controlled by window size of the user).

```js
function log() {
  console.log("Click!");
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.zoom {
  display: block;
  max-height: max-content;
  max-width: max-content;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: aqua;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 500px; display: flex; flex-direction: row; overflow: scroll; background-color: lightgray">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="zoom" onclick="log()">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/Eiffel_Tower_Vertical.JPG" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="zoom" onclick="log()">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Eiffel_tower_at_dawn_horizontal.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Desired result:

I have two divs (`.container`, green) and (`.zoom`, aqua). Container's size is based on the users window size, not fixed. Zoom contains an image, which should use as much of `.container`s area (preserving aspect ratio) and should be centered. Depending on the aspect ratio of the image this either leaves space to the sides or top and bottom of the picture. I need to get `.zoom`s size to exactly match the size of the image as an event handler is bound to that.

The green area shows the `.container` while the aqua area shows one of two images (in the example one portrait and one landscape). The dimensions and position of `.zoom` should match this image.

[image]

Comment: Divs take by default the dimension of it's content, so in your code just add height: auto;
  width: auto; to .zomm class

Comment: @Sfili_81 that leads to the vertical image overflowing vertically which I don't want

Comment: what do you mean with 'overflowing vertically which I don't want '? it's not clear. Please post an image of what is the desired result

Comment: I copied your snippet to check and... I don't exactly understand what you are looking! Could you at least put a drawing of what you are expecting, both for desktop and mobile

Comment: I've added pictures of the desired result. The green area should not be affected by the image, the aqua area should be the size of the image whilst following aspect ratio and max-width/ max-height constraints. @pierfarrugia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I've got an working example using `display: flex` with help from @DataMoose:

```js
function log() {
 console.log("Click!");
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.zoom {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
 
  background-color: aqua;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 300px; display: flex; flex-direction: row; overflow: scroll; background-color: lightgray">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="zoom" onclick="log()">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/Eiffel_Tower_Vertical.JPG" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="zoom" onclick="log()">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Eiffel_tower_at_dawn_horizontal.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could set img { display: block;} or img {vertical-align: bottom;} to remove the whitespace underneath the image. 

The empty space is not padding. Images have a display of inline by default. This cause some strange behavior where the containing div will have extra whitespace below the image for descenders (the bits that hang off the bottom of 'y' and 'p').

Comment: Thanks @DataMoose. That was the missing piece to the puzzle, I've updated and accepted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let button = document.querySelector("button");
let imgs = document.querySelectorAll("img");

button.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
  for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].classList.toggle("hidden");
  }
});
```

```css
div{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  outline: 1px dashed blue;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<button>switch</button>
<div>
<img src="https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/cc/us/en/creative-cloud/photography/discover/landscape-photography/CODERED_B1_landscape_P2d_714x348.jpg.img.jpg" alt="pic1">

<img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61WYsP5qScL.jpg" alt="pic1" class="hidden">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try using `display: flex` myself, didn't think of that before. This mostly works but the second (portrait) image gets stretched horizontally for me. Any easy way to fix this? Also: I need a second inner div with the exact dimensions of the image.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a really good opportunity to use background-image in CSS!  There are a number of fields such as background-image, background-repeat, background-size, background-position in CSS that can all be used to help us use images in a box.  The only difference is that if we wanted to swap it out in JS, we would just have to set a new value for style.backgroundImage.

When you run the following code snippet, try editing the picsum image size or other properties for background- properties!

```css
#img-container-wide {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/200/300");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}

#img-container-tall {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/200/300");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="img-container-wide"></div>
<div id="img-container-tall"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution with `flex` causes the image to jump between centered and left alignment when the browser window size changes, and the right image is never centered when the available space is larger than the image width (at least in Safari 16.2). As I understood your question, it should work regardless of the window size. The following CSS will center `.zoom` vertically and horizontally within `.container` while making `.zoom` the size of the image and maintaining the image's aspect ratio regardless of the window size:

```css
.outside-div {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.zoom {
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Since you mentioned that you don't know what size the images will actually be, I added some JS that will retrieve random size images for the demo:

```js
/* just for demo */
let img_one = document.getElementById("img-1");
let img_two = document.getElementById("img-2");


function changeImages() {
  setImage(img_one, 800, 1200);
  setImage(img_two, 1800, 800);
}

function setImage(img, x, y) {
  img.setAttribute("src", `https://picsum.photos/${x-randomInt(50,400)}/${y-randomInt(50,400)}`);
}

function randomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}
```

```css
/* just for demo */

.outside-div.demo {
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.container.demo {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.zoom.demo {
  background-color: aqua;
}


/* needed */

.outside-div {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.zoom {
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
Click this button to add/change images <button onclick="changeImages()">
  Change Images
</button>

<div class="outside-div demo">
  <div class="container demo">
    <div class="zoom demo">
      <img id="img-1" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container demo">
    <div class="zoom demo">
      <img id="img-2" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set img { display: block;} or img {vertical-align: bottom;} to remove the whitespace underneath the image. The empty space is not padding. Images have a display of inline by default. This cause some strange behavior where the containing div will have extra whitespace below the image for descenders (the bits that hang off the bottom of 'y' and 'p')

Comment: Even though this is not really an complete answer I will reward you the bounty as you solved the last issue and as I mostly answered the question myself apart from that. Thank you! See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74971769/10816438 for the complete answer.